# failed to lazily initialize a collection and vaadin

Tags: java, hibernate, vaadin, lazy-loading

Hello I have a problem with vaadin and lazy load of my entity
my entity contains a rellationship one-to-many and many-to-one with this way

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "Categories")
public class Category extends AbstractEntity {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String name;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "parent")
private Category parent; 
@Column
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Category> children = new ArrayList<>(); 

public Category() { }
```

so i have this controller

```
  @Transactional 
  public class CategoryService{

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;


public void save(Category category) {
     ..
}


public Collection<Category> all() {
    return em
            .createQuery("select category  from Category category",Category.class)
            .getResultList();

}
```

when i try to load and  print for each entity her children it was successfull but it was on setup.When i use my form in vaadin and i call service.all()
and try to do the same thing i have the

> *org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily
>   initialize a collection of role: models.Category.children, could not
>   initialize proxy - no Session*

Service:

```
@Inject 
public CategoriesView(CategoryService service) { 
    this.service = service; 
    list= (List<Category>) service.all(); 
} 

@Override 
protected Component initContent() { 
    HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout(); 
    for (Category cate : list) { 
        System.out.println(cate.getChildren()); 
    }
}
```

What can  i do to have wanted result?

Comment: Remove Cascading from entity relationship cascade= {CascadeType.ALL} and check.

Comment: @kc007 nothing happend, i was wondering if there is any annotation for my view
so it can keep the session alive

Comment: There is proporty has to added in application.proporties as by default that true which do not load lazy, you have to make it false, I don’t remember that need to check that property name then it should work, let me check that.

Comment: Can you please put method @transactional notation in service and check

Comment: @kc007 already have one :/

Comment: Ok put this under application property hibernate.enabled_lazy_load_no_trans=true please check spells correctly as I just typed

Comment: Where do you call CategoryService.all()? and where do you call Category.getChildren()? Can we see that code?

Comment: @Priyesh 
       @-Inject
       public CategoriesView(CategoryService service) {
            this.service = service; 
            list= (List<Category>) service.all();
        }

          @-Override
           protected Component initContent() {
           HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
             for (Category cate : list) {
                System.out.println(cate.getChildren());
            }

Answer (score 1):

i solved my problem by this way
i initialized my data-providers in my enter method and i did this

```
    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
    parents = DataProvider.ofCollection(service.all());
    parentGrid.setDataProvider(parents);

}
```

edit also i put my selectionListener into the enter method